# What are the 7 Noachide Laws

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah

What are the 7 Noachide Laws? And where do we know them from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apart from not murdering and not eating meat from a live animal, where are the Noachide laws derived from?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/94221/apart-from-not-murdering-and-not-eating-meat-from-a-live-animal-where-are-the-n)

Comment: @DannySchoemann Explain to me how this eight-year-old question is a dupe of the one from this morning? You say it’s because that one has a better answer - questions shouldn’t be gauged based on their answers. The mods can take that answer and put it on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary codification of the Sheva Mitzvos B'nei Noach, the Seven Noachide Laws, can be found in the Rambam's Mishneh Torah [also known as Yad Chazakah] Hilchos Melachim 9:1 and are elaborated upon in chapters 9 and 10.

According to the Rambam they consist of the prohibition against Avodah Zarah (Idolatry),against cursing G-d, against Murder, against giluy arayos (incest/adultery), theft, eating flesh from a live animal, and the positive command to establish courts.

The source[s] of these mitzvos in Chazal are Sanhedrin 56a and Genesis Rabba 16:6.