# Apart from not murdering and not eating meat from a live animal, where are the Noachide laws derived from?

Tags: noachide-laws

Apart from not murdering and not eating meat from a live animal, where are the Noachide laws derived from? Those aforementioned are mentioned in [Genesis 9:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#6), but where (outside the laws of Moses) is it a given to follow the other laws?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1537/15256

Comment: @Kazibácsi Dupe, since that asks where we know them from, not just what they are?

Comment: @mbloch - this has a better answer - I'm tempted to close the other one as a dup.

Answer (score 5):

The logic is given by Rambam in Mishneh Torah [Melakhim uMilchamot 9:1](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188354/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-9.htm):

> על ששה דברים נצטווה אדם הראשון [...] הוסיף לנח אבר מן החי שנאמר אך בשר בנפשו דמו לא תאכלו נמצאו שבע מצות
>
> Six precepts were commanded to Adam. [...] The prohibition against eating flesh from a living animal was added for Noah, as it is stated (Bereishit 9:4): *'Nevertheless, you may not eat flesh with its life, which is its blood.'* Thus there are seven mitzvot.

(See also [Sanhedrin 56a](http://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_56.html) and [Bereishit Rabbah 34:8](https://archive.org/stream/RabbaGenesis/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n319))

So you have to go back to Adam to see these six laws that are listed with their sources in [Bereishit Rabbah 16:6](https://archive.org/stream/RabbaGenesis/midrashrabbahgen027557mbp#page/n178). Five are based on the method called [gezeirah shavah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmudical_hermeneutics#Gezerah_shavah_(%D7%92%D7%96%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%94)) that derives teachings based on common words in different verses. [Bereishit 2:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0102.htm#16) was divided into six parts by the sages referring to six commandments:

- **idolatry** – וַיְצַו: based on the common word צו also found in [Hoshea 5:11](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1305.htm#11)
- **blasphemy** – 'ה: *Hashem* alludes to [Vayikra 24:16](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0324.htm#16)
- **judges** – אֱלֹקִים: the other divine name, *Elokim* alludes to [Shemot 22:27](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm#27)
- **(bloodshed** – עַל־הָאָדָם: *man* alludes to [Bereishit 9:6](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0109.htm#6))
- **incest** – לֵאמֹר: *saying* alludes to [Yirmiyahu 3:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1103.htm#1)
- **theft** – מִכֹּל עֵץ־הַגָּן אָכֹל תֹּאכֵל: *Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat* alludes to the fact that one needs a permission from an owner to take her/his property.

(See also [Sanhedrin 56b](http://halakhah.com/sanhedrin/sanhedrin_56.html#PARTb))

Another great article from [MyJewishLearning.com](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-noahide-laws/) regarding the question.

Comment: @Reggie Do you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: It includes reference to the Mosaic law, I'm not entirely sure how they all apply to everyone. But as a Noachide myself it's good to see there is a biblical justification for theft being a sin.

Comment: @Reggie The precise meaning of a verse that applies to all Noachides is derived through a method that uses other verses. But it doesn't change the applicability. We simply ask what is the exact meaning of the verse that commanded Adam.