# Modesty for a Goya

Tags: gentiles, internet, tznius-modesty, lifnei-iver, social-media

My Noahide female friend has taken on modest attire, so as not to be a stumbling block.
There are still pictures of her on friends' social media, in many of these she is dressed immodestly.

**My questions are:**
Is there a source as to whether or not modesty (as it applies to lifnei iver) applies to non-Jewish women?

Does my friend have an obligation to get all these photos taken down, does she make a sin if someone sins as a result of her photos even if she is not the one hosting them?

Does she circumvent the issue if she converts, because she is a new person, or does she still get any new sins made if someone sees those photos?

*Thank you everyone, I apologize if my question is longwinded or improperly formatted, I'm new here :)*

Comment: Is modesty among the seven Noachide laws? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94225/15256

Comment: @Kazi is it among the 613 Jewish laws?

Comment: @DoubleAA lifnei iver? Or you mean its application to modesty

Comment: @robev obviously im not discussing lifnei iver which is explicitly one of the 613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first angle that needs to be addressed is if there’s a problem of lifnei iver for a non-Jew. Tosfos in Avodah Zara 15b (L'oved) says that a non-Jew does not have the issur of lifnei iver. However, the Pri Migadim in Ginas Veradim (klal 43) says that a non-Jew does have the issur of lifnei iver. The Minchas Chinuch (mitzvah 232) argues, and the Sdei Chemed (6:23) brings a whole list of Achronim who argue and mentions Tosfos as well as one who argues.

So according to most authorities, there would be no problem of lifnei iver in this case.

As far as the general issue of dressing immodesty in front of non-Jews (assuming that the pictures are being seen only by non-Jews, a highly debatable point) this link from dinonline brings sources that it is a problem
https://dinonline.org/2019/07/08/erva-in-front-of-goy/

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of the final paragraph. Isn't that addressing a Jew's responsibility vis-a-vis non-Jews? Here we're addressing non-Jews to non-Jews

Comment: @robev although the OP was asking about a non Jew dressed immodestly, there is a point to consider about the fact that non Jews are the ones seeing it and therefore may not even be considered an aveira even for a Jew to do in front of them. (See comments on the question) Hence the link that this is not a consideration